# CS50 Credit: Always getting INVALID return

Tags: cs50

Was attempting Credit from CS50 and kept getting INVALID return from my code. I approached this problem by using arrays even though it may not have been the best method. Code compiles with no issues.

My pseudocode logic was:

1) obtain card number

2) use loop to find number of digits

3) check if card contains 13, 15 or 16 digits

4) if so, write digits from long into array

5) have a copy of original array to multiply every other number by 2

6) add the digits of the product

7) check for card length and starting digits

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Get credit card number
    long num = get_long("Number: ");

    // Find number of digits
    int digits = 0;
    while (num > 0)
    {
        num /= 10;
        digits++;
    }

    // Check if number of digits is within possible range
    if (digits != 13 && digits != 15 && digits != 16)
    {
       printf("INVALID\n");
    }

    int originalnumber[digits];

    // Write each digit of credit card number into an array
    for (int i = digits - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        originalnumber[i] = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }

    // Multiply alternate digits by 2
    int number[digits];
    for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++)
    {
        number[i] = originalnumber[i];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < digits; i+=2)
    {
        number[i] = number[i] * 2;
    }

    // Add product digits
    int sum = 0;
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++)
    {
        temp = (number[i] % 10) + ((number[i] / 10) % 10);
        sum = sum + temp;
    }

    // Check for card length and starting digits

    // AMEX
    if (digits == 15)
    {
        if (originalnumber[14] == 3 && sum % 10 == 0 && (originalnumber[13] == 4 || originalnumber[13] == 7))
        {
            printf("AMEX\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // MasterCard
    if (digits == 16)
    {
        if (originalnumber[15] == 5 && sum % 10 == 0 && (originalnumber[14] == 1 || originalnumber[14] == 2 || originalnumber[14] == 3 || originalnumber[14] == 4 || originalnumber[14] == 5))
        {
            printf("MASTERCARD\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // Visa
    if (digits == 13)
    {
        if (originalnumber[12] == 4 && sum % 10 == 0)
        {
            printf("VISA\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if (digits == 16)
    {
        if (originalnumber[15] == 4 && sum % 10 == 0)
        {
            printf("VISA\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("INVALID\n");
    return 1;
}
```

I tried debug50 and it seems that when I try to sum the digits together using temp and sum, the loop completes with sum still being 0. May I know what is wrong here? Is the flow of my pseudocode wrong or are there any glaring mistakes that I may have overlooked? (stared at this for way too long..)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sum` is always 0, regardless of whether that is what you expect,  `sum % 10` would always be 0, so that is not the "false" that is failing the tests.

Which should direct your attention to `originalnumber`.

What is the value of `num` after this loop?

```
 while (num > 0)
 {
     num /= 10;
     digits++;
 }
```

Comment: Just submitted this problem set with everything correct on check50 :-)
Realising how the value of `num` changed got the ball rolling! Tidied up some other of the for loop conditions as I thought I was storing the credit card number in the array in reverse order but it turns out that I was supposed to store it in the right order, except that the array is filled from the back to the front instead.
Appreciate the help.